# Renaming image files if statement is false

Tags: python, image

So explained briefly I have a folder where I put some images into. The name of the images are integers, so for example I could have 5 images with the names 567.jpg, 568.jpg, 569.jpg, 570.jpg, and 571.jpg. The integer numbers are random, however, they always come in a sequence like above, i.e. increasing by one for every image.

So what I want to do is to go through the images in this folder and look at the image size. If the width of an image is under 600px (as an example) I want to delete this image and move on to the next image. Now, if this image is then above 600px it should be renamed such as it follows the sequence.

So in principle what should happen is:

345.jpg --> Over 600px --> Nothing happens
346-jpg --> Under 600px --> Gets deleted
347.jph --> Over 600px --> Gets renamed to 346.jpg (to follow the 1 step sequence)

And so on...

I have tried with the following code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

img_dir_path = "\"

pic_list = range(567,572,1)

for image in pic_list:
    img = Image.open("{}/{}.jpg".format(img_dir_path, image))
    if img.size[0] < 600:
        os.remove("{}/{}.jpg".format(img_dir_path, image))
    else:
        if os.path.isfile("{}/{}.jpg".format(img_dir_path, int(image)-1)) == False:
            os.rename('{}/{}.jpg'.format(img_dir_path, int(image)), '{}/{}.jpg'.format(img_dir_path, int(image)-1))
        else:
            print "No worries"
```

However, when doing so I get the follow error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

For the rename process that it...

I know this is some sloppy code, but I'm not a Python expert yet, so I usually just make it work first, and then tweak.

In addition, another problem that arises is that when checking if the entry before the true first entry exists / is false, it always is false now since there of course is nothing before the first image. Therefore, the image with the first name in the list should of course not be renamed. However, since I couldn't even get this to work, I wasn't going to try to fix that.

Comment: Do close the image which is opened before renaming img = Image.open("{}/{}.jpg".format(img_dir_path, image))

Comment: Image.close() before rename

Comment: Yup, that was it. Make an answer if you want an answer accepted :)

Comment: Thanks @ Denver Dang added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do close the image which is opened before renaming `img = Image.open("{}/{}.jpg".format(img_dir_path, image))`

```
Image.close()
```

before rename